# by default aspNetDisabled class assigned to dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, css, drop-down-menu

I have added a dropdownlist to gridview column, i set the dropdownlist property `Enable=false`, it adds automatically `aspNetDisabled` to class attribute of select box, my CSS for disabled list does not have any effect on it. How can i avoid `aspNetDisabled`?

Comment: in my css i added class aspNetDisabled and set its background-color: yellow; it works, but when i set background-color: transparent; its background becomes blue in disabled mode, im still unable to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, the only way I've found to override this behaviour is via the DisabledCssClass attribute on the WebControl:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.disabledcssclass.aspx